# How to efficiently parallelize LINQ Except method

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, task-parallel-library, parallel-extensions

I was wondering how this could be achieved in the most efficient way.

Should I use

```
a.RemoveAll(x => b.AsParallel().Any(y => y == x));
```

or

```
a.AsParallel().Except(b.AsParallel());
```

or something else?

Can anyone explain what the underlying difference is? It seems to me, from measuring, that the second line is slower. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Why are you asking us to [race your horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)? (Test them out, find out which is faster, and if it still is not fast enough for your use case, *then* come back here with your example code and ask "this is too slow, can I make it faster?")

Comment: Is it still slower when you run in release mode with the debugger not attached?

Comment: The two queries are not equivalent. The first one operates on two lists, the second one on three (because you need a third list to store the results. Even if it is assigned to `a` there will be a temporary list in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the second option, with two `ParallelQuery<T>` operations, will perform the entire operation in parallel:

```
var results = a.AsParallel().Except(b.AsParallel());
```

The first option does a sequential check for the removal, and must build the `ParallelQuery<T>` for each iteration, which will likely be far slower.

Depending on the number of elements, however, it may actually be faster to run this without `AsParallel`:

```
var results = a.Except(b);
```

In many cases, the overhead of parallelizing for smaller collections outweighs the gains.  The only way to know, in this case, would be to profile and measure the options involved.

> It seems to me, from measuring, that the second line is slower. What is the reason for this?

This may be due to a lot of factors.  First, make sure you're running outside of the VS host in a release build (this is a common issue).  Otherwise, this may be due to the size of the collections, and data types involved.

Comment: I have tried that, but it throws an exception if `b` isn't used as parallel.

Comment: @IgorSevo Realized that as I was typing - corrected.